# Django Paginated Comments .. is there any existing solutions?

Tags: django, django-templates, comments, pagination, templatetags

is there any existing pagination solution for Django contrib.comments?

What I need is just a simple paginated django comments, for the Basic Blog application (from the Django Basic Apps) I used, using a [simple has_previous and has_next](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/UsingFreeComment)

I have copied the django.contrib.comments and tried modify the code but with no success. The code is pretty hard to understand (django/contrib/comments/templatetags/comments.py) because it consists of Node and Parser

here is my comments.html template I used for the Blog application:

```
{% load comments markup %}
{% get_comment_list for object as comment_list %}
    {% if comment_list %}
    <div class="comments g_7 left">
        <a name="comments"></a>
        <div class="subtitle">Comments</div>
        {% for comment in comment_list %}
            {% if comment.is_public %}
            <div class="comment g_6" id="c{{ comment.id }}">
                <div class="comment_name g_6">
                <div class="comment_count right">
                    <a name="c{{ comment.id }}" href="{{ comment.get_absolute_url }}" {% ifnotequal comment.person_name null %}title="Permalink to {{ comment.person_name }}'s comment"{% endifnotequal %} class="comment_count">{{ forloop.counter }}</a></div>
                    Wrote by <strong>{% if comment.user_url %}<a href="{{ comment.user_url }}">{{ comment.user_name }}</a>{% else %}{{ comment.user_name }}{% endif %}</strong> on {{ comment.submit_date|date:"F j, Y" }} - {{ comment.submit_date|date:"P" }} 
                </div>
                <div class="comment_body g_6">{{ comment.comment|urlizetrunc:"60"|safe }}</div>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    {% else %}
        No comments yet.
    {% endif %}
```

I think the problem lies in the **get_comment_list** templatetags :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think django-pagination might be what you're looking for.

http://code.google.com/p/django-pagination/ (screencast available)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer :)

Actually I'm looking for the specific comment pagination, that someone might have done previously (I suppose comment is a common feature and someone must've done the pagination in the comment solution) but I think the link you gave me can provide the workaround :)

I'll try to play with it. thanks!

Comment: +1 django-pagination is a great way to solve this; it's as easy as putting it in your INSTALLED_APPS and adding two lines to your template: "{% autopaginate comment_list %}" before you loop through it and (wherever you want the pagination controls) "{% pagination %}".

Answer (score 0):

Django also has a built in Pagination system

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/