# What is the cleanest/simplest way to paginate django comments?

Tags: django, django-comments

Using Django's built in comment framework what is the cleanest/simplest way to the paginate comments?

Comment: Previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028229/django-paginated-comments-is-there-any-existing-solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Django's Built-In Pagination Framework.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/

Or Google Code Django-Pagination.

http://code.google.com/p/django-pagination/

Answer (score 5):

Or Django Endless Pagination:
http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/